# Webtest in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, webtest, data-driven-tests

I need to perform a webtest for online webservice which adds two numbers and display the result, here now, i need to provide input from a csv file (excel sheet) like 2 columns a and b with 3 or 4 values each, i need to perform webtest and print the results to another new csv file... i am searching for solution, please kind of you if you can help me with this! I need you to provide the coding done in the .cs(class file) on how to read the values from my data source and store them in my context parameter input variable. I am waiting for a solution
please clearly tell me the modification to be done in webtest also.

Comment: Have you read any sample/document?

Comment: i tried alot... there is no proper answer available in web